# couldn't find download button on github website

Tags: android, download, google-play-games

I'm trying to set up a google play service library  in my app and I need to download the basegameutils. But I really have no idea how to download this sample on this site...
It really seems a mystery to me..
EDIT: I was overlooking the download button on the lower right side of the screen.

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the right hand side column near the bottom, there is a button that says **Download zip**. If you click that it will download the entire **android-basic-samples** folder. Within that folder, you will fine BaseGameUtiles under **BasicSamples > Libraries > BaseGameUtils**.